# Chrome keeps using helvetica font

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I've recently installed a helvetica font on my computer and ever since, Chrome has been trying to use it - on site like ebay, netflix, etc. I've checked the "customize fonts" option and Helvetica isn't seleceted anywhere in there. When I try to remove the font from Windows, it says it's "in use" and I can't remove it. I could try booting into safe mode to do it, but I would really  prefer to keep the font (I'm using it to create a resume). How can I stop chrome from trying to use Helvetica?

Comment: Have you tried resetting the browser?

Comment: Are you sure it's not the websites that are using the font?

Answer (score 1):

Browse to

> C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets\Custom.css

And add to the end of the file:

> @font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }

Take a look at the following link.
http://thomaslittle.tumblr.com/post/13973246295/chrome-helvetica-bug-fix-for-windows-7

***EDIT***

Try the Stylebot extension for Chrome.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I don't have a 'User StyleSheets' folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprits were Helvetica Light & Compressed. Fixed the issue by renaming these fonts via **Msconfig -> Boot -> SafeBoot -> Alternate Shell.**

Once you reboot, you will need to use the command prompt and the "ren" command to rename the files. Location of said files is in: "C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts".

Everything looks GREAT in Chrome now!  [location of custom fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvzDs.png)